# How can I prevent implicit conversions in a function template?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

How can I define a function template to prevent implicit conversions?

It seems I can prevent implicit conversions using non-template functions but not using function templates.

Defining a forwarding reference function template as `= delete` is too aggressive as it prevents invocation with non-const lvalue references.

Defining an function template with a const rvalue argument as `=delete` [1]
does not prevent implicit conversions.

Defining an rvalue overload for a specific type as `=delete` works but I'd like to accomplish this with templates.

Minimal code example:

```
struct A {};

struct B {
  B() = default;

  B(const A&) {}
};

// Delete const rvalue reference.
template <class T>
void t_no_rvalue(const T&&) = delete; // 1

void t_no_rvalue(const B&) {}         // 2


// Delete forwarding reference.
template <class T>
void t_no_fwd_ref(T&&) = delete;     // 3

void t_no_fwd_ref(const B&) {}       // 4


// (non-template) Delete const rvalue reference.
void no_rvalue(const B&&) = delete;  // 5

void no_rvalue(const B&) {}          // 6


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  A a;
  B b;

  // Undesired behaviour, implicit conversion allowed.
  t_no_rvalue(a);   // resolves to 2
  t_no_rvalue(b);   // resolves to 2

  // Undesired behaviour, invocation with non-const reference disallowed.
  t_no_fwd_ref(a);  // resolves to 3
  t_no_fwd_ref(b);  // resolves to 3

  // Desired behaviour.
  no_rvalue(a);     // resolves to 5
  no_rvalue(b);     // resolves to 6
}
```

My real-world use case is hashing of variants where implicit conversion of a variant sub-type back to the variant-like type will cause infinite recursion if the hash function is not specialized for all the variant constituents. The sample code above is clearer though.

[1] Attempted in [Why can I prevent implicit conversions for primitives but not user-defined types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989414/why-can-i-prevent-implicit-conversions-for-primitives-but-not-user-defined-types) but with a broken code example.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking - i.e. why does `no_rvalue` not solve your problem?  You mention you want a template, but what would the template parameters be?  It might help if you provide a `main()` showing more examples of what should or shouldn't compile.

Comment: Rather than subjecting yourself with dealing with ICS hullabaloo as regards to dealing with *functions*. Why don't you require your users to specialize a *class-template* instead of overload a *function*. I think you should explore the use of *class-template* specializations or some other machinery. Think of how `std::hash` was designed.

Comment: `explicit B(const A&){}` ??

Comment: @M.M. no_rvalue has the desired behaviour but I don't want the user to specify two non-template functions. I'd rather provide one deleted version and have the user specify the one they will implement.

Comment: @Praveen That stops all implicit conversions which is more aggressive than I want. I also may not be able to change the explicit nature of the class constructor (std::variant for instance).

Comment: @WhiZTiM. I can use class-template specializations but that subjects users to (possibly avoidable) boilerplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following overload will prevent implicit conversions:

```
template <class T>
void no_conversions(T) = delete; // 7

void no_conversions(const B&) {} // 8
```

and leads to:

```
// Requested behaviour.
no_conversions(a); // resolves to 7
no_conversions(b); // resolves to 8
```

A value-overload poisons the overload set for implicit conversions as it will be an exact match.

Edit:

```
template <class T>
void no_conversions(const T&) = delete; // 9

void no_conversions(const B&) {}        // 10
```

works just as well.

Comment: The latter case, `const T&`, is preferable for poisoning because it doesn't cause any unrelated errors with potentially deleted copy or move constructors of `T`.

Comment: Thanks, nice to pick one of the approaches. Do you have an example of the confusing errors?

Comment: For example, consider a class like `struct X { X(X&&) = delete; /* ... */}`. Using the by-value version, GCC will unnecessarily complain that the copy constructor is deleted: https://wandbox.org/permlink/TTSATJZNr53RJUKQ. Clang is a bit better and puts the relevant error first (https://wandbox.org/permlink/TTSATJZNr53RJUKQ), but you still clutter up the error output with irrelevant things. By using the reference version you avoid considering copies altogether and focus only on the thing you actually mean.