# Use a C++ template to define a function but explicitly delete it to prevent misuse

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion, deleted-functions

I have a template class with a constructor in which I want to explicitly forbid the usage of any type beyond a well defined list, like this:

```
template<typename Anything>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int &);
    MyClass(float &);
    MyClass(Anything &) = delete;
}
```

However, since the code for the **integer** and the **double** version are identical, and only differ in the type, I'd like to define it using the templatized version, such as:

```
template<typename Anything>
MyClass<Anything>::MyClass(Anything &var)
{
    /* Code that operates over var */
    ...
}
```

instead of virtually having to duplicate the code for both valid constructors.

However, when I tried to do so, I get:

```
error: redefinition of 'MyClass<Anything>::MyClass(Anything&)'
```

It works by removing the **"= delete"**.

Is there a way to use the template to define the function but without explicitly allowing to receive more types than the ones also explicitly described?

I checked [How can I prevent implicit conversions in a function template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995946/how-can-i-prevent-implicit-conversions-in-a-function-template) and also [Why can I prevent implicit conversions for primitives but not user-defined types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989414/why-can-i-prevent-implicit-conversions-for-primitives-but-not-user-defined-types), but their issues don't seem to be equivalent to the current one.

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE: Using gcc-4.8.5, it works!!! Even with the **= delete** keyword included.

Comment: Did you mean to make `MyClass::MyClass(Anything)` the template, instead of the whole class? If you only want to disable all other constructors, you should not template the whole class, just that constructor.

Comment: Is `MyClass(float &);` suppose to be `MyClass(double &);`? Your question mentions *"... the integer and the double version ..."*.

Comment: With a somewhat more concrete example we should be able to give you better advice.

Comment: About your questions:

1.- The whole class has to be templatized, not just the constructor, I've other members that also depend on the template types.
2.- Yes, it's float, my typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your definition is that you're trying to implement the exact function that you have marked with `= delete`.

You actually want another function template that works with both `int` and `float`. You can achieve that by first defining an `IntOrFloat` predicate:

```
template <typename T>
using IntOrFloat = std::bool_constant<
    std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, float>>;
```

Then you can define two unambiguous constructors that use `std::enable_if_t` to check whether or not the predicate is fulfilled by the type passed in by the user:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    template <typename T, 
              std::enable_if_t<IntOrFloat<T>{}>* = nullptr>
    MyClass(T&);

    template <typename Anything, 
              std::enable_if_t<!IntOrFloat<Anything>{}>* = nullptr>
    MyClass(Anything&) = delete;
};
```

Usage example:

```
int main()
{
    int v0 = 0;
    float v1 = 0.f;
    const char* v2 = "igijsdg";

    MyClass x0{v0}; // OK
    MyClass x1{v1}; // OK
    MyClass x2{v2}; // Error
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YPpE5AdqQjYVV4Rq)

Comment: `std::bool_constant` is a alias template for `std::integral_constant<bool, Condition>`

Comment: Use `template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<cond>* = nullptr>` to avoid to have `Dummy = int`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, applied both.